# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `'' while using sed

Tags: bash, sed, sh

Yes this question has been asked many times, and in the answer it is said to us `\` escape character before the single quote.

In the below code it isn't working:

```
LIST="(96634,IV14075295,TR14075685')"
LIST=`echo $LIST | sed 's/,/AAA/g' `
echo $LIST                      # Output: (96634AAAIV14075295AAATR14075685')

# Now i want to quote the list elements
LIST=`echo $LIST | sed 's/,/\',\'/g' `  # Giving error

# exit 0
```

**Error :**

```
line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Do not use old and outdated backtics, use parentheses `var=$(code)`.  And always double quote variables `echo "$LIST"` (Its ok to not double quote one a single line variable, but it's not a good practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of single quotes, use double quotes in sed command, and also remove the space before last backtick.  If there is single quote present in the sed pattern then use an alternative enclosing quotes(ie, double quotes),

```
sed "s/,/\',\'/g"
```

And the line would be,

```
LIST=$(echo $LIST | sed "s/,/\',\'/g")
```

Don't use backticks inside the sripts instead of bacticks, use `$()`

Comment: but my question is why the escape character is not working using single quotes :)

Comment: Do not use old and outdated backtics, use parentheses like this: `LIST=$(echo "$LIST" | sed "s/,/\',\'/g")`.  And double quote variable to preserve new line etc.

Comment: @Bharat you could see the difference by running these two commands `echo '\''` and `echo '\'`. Sed uses Basic regular expression. The first echo command won't work because the interpreter after seeing the second `'`, it considers it as string end  and the escape character before the second `'` is treated as literal. Likewise the same operation is done on the sed.

Comment: @AvinashRaj that's true but i used pipe to redirect the echo's output to sed , i m not using any escape character inside the echo.

Comment: i mean the echo commands in the above comment, not the one in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`

```
echo $LIST
(96634,IV14075295,TR14075685')

LIST=$(awk '{gsub(/,/,q"&"q)};gsub(/\(/,"&"q)1' q="'" <<< $LIST)

echo $LIST
('96634','IV14075295','TR14075685')
```

To prevent problems with the single quote, I just set it to an `awk` variable.

Answer (score 0):

consider

```
LIST="$(sed "s/,/\',\'/g" <<< "$LIST")"
```

but first and last elements probably won't get quoted completely, because of missing leading and trailing comma

btw, you don't need to subshell to sed - string matching and substitution is entirely within the capabilities of bash:

```
LIST="${LIST//,/\',\'}"
```

Comment: This is just a copy of Avinashs post, same `sed` only moved input. And first element is not quoted..

Comment: it can be duplicate reply but +1 for mentioning to use `<<< "$LIST"`

Comment: Should have been an edit then instead of a new answer.  Also Deleted User isn't actually a deleted user, in case that's not clear.